# Rendering pageblock from visualforce remoting

Tags: javascript-remoting

I have a requirement where I need to render component from visualforce remoting.

If I would have used actionsupport instead of visualforce remoting, I can use rerender attribute to render certain pageblock.
I am wondering how to render pageblock on click of javascrip remoting value

Comment: Can you elaborate on your solution design ? To me it is strange that 1 server-client round trip should fire off another one to get the result you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an actionFunction without action which only rerends your pageBlock and called it from your javascript Remoting.

```
Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
            '{!$RemoteAction.MyController.doSomething}',
            recordId,
            function(result, event)
            {
                rerendAction();
            });

<apex:actionFunction name="rerendAction" rerender="myblockToRerend"/>
```

Comment: thanks,                                                            What should be in rerenderAction() function.??

Comment: Nothing. your rerendAction() is your actionFunction itself which will rerend your pageBlock.

Comment: Thanks ... can u help me in this which I am findint difficulty after rendering pageblock                                                http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23244/getting-values-when-clicked-on-pop-up