# Getting values when clicked on Pop-Up

Tags: visualforce, javascript-remoting

Thanks for the reply.

It helped me. 
Now can I get the values in that rendered pageblock.

My requirement is I have a mpa where I need to click on zip whose values are coming from "javascrip remoting" and as you said I used "actionfunction" and could able to render popup. Now my requiremnt is "On click on the zip I need to get values in that pop".

```
Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction
                   (
                     '{!$RemoteAction.Arun_map_1.getAdjacent_Terr}',
                       zip_id,
                       function(result, event) {
                        adjacent = result
                        //alert("Wating....")
                        console.log("adjacent :- " + adjacent)
                        if (adjacent.toString() == 'true'){
                          var query = new esri.tasks.Query();
                          query.geometry = evt.mapPoint;
                          var deferred = zipcodes.selectFeatures(query,esri.layers.FeatureLayer.SELECTION_NEW);
                          console.log(evt.mapPoint);
                          rerendAction();
                        //  zip_indicator()
                          }
                        else{
                        alert("Selected zip is not adjacent ..please select adjacent zip")
                       }




                    });
```

---

```
<apex:actionFunction name="rerendAction" rerender="popup" action="{!showPopup1}" />
```

---

```
     <apex:outputPanel styleClass="popupBackground" layout="block"  rendered="{!displayPopUp}"/>
        <apex:outputPanel styleClass="customPopup" layout="block" rendered="{!displayPopUp}">

            <apex:outputtext value="zipname.name"/>


        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:outputPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the variable to the controller using the action function:

Javascript change:

```
rerendAction(adjacent);
```

VF Change

```
<apex:actionFunction name="rerendAction" rerender="popup" action="{!showPopup1}" >
     <apex:param value="dummy" name="popUpValue" assignTo="{!VARTOASSIGNTO}"/>
</apex:actionFunction>
```

Then in your popup add

```
<apex:outputtext value="{!VARTOASSIGNTO}"/>
```

Since you are calling the showPopUp1 method in your actionFunction the variable passed to the param should be set when the popUp is rendered.

Please give it a try and let us know

Comment: Thanks Eric,I followed your suggestion. I am facing problem to write this in SOQL "where name = : zip_id". Please help me..                                                       public void showPopup1( )
 {
  displayPopup = true;
  soql= [select id,name,territory_id__c from zip__c limit 1]
  name = string.valueof(soql);
  system.debug('Name'+name);
  }

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. Your RemoteAction is returning a value and you asked for that value to be displayed in the popup. Why are you needing an SOQL as you should be passing it to the controller when the remote action returns

Comment: Remote Action is returning boolean value and I need to display value of clicked zip in pop-up which I need to get from SOQL.

Comment: Isn't the clicked zip in your 'zip_id' JavaScript variable?